# using ajax to submit form from another page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form on one page with `action="/profile"` and I am trying to make an Ajax code to make it update without page refresh and without having to go to that page. Any ideas on how I go about this or if I am actually do it right or what?

```
$(function() {  
   $('.error').hide();  
     $("#submit").click(function() {  
// validate and process form here  
$('.error').hide();  
  var stat = $("#profile_field_13_5").val();  
    if (stat == "") {  
  $("#name_error").show();  
  $("#profile_field_13_5").focus();  
  return false;  
}  
var dataString = 'stat='+ stat ;
 $.ajax({  
          type: "POST",  
          url: "/profile.php",  
          data: dataString,  
          success: function() {  
     $('#statsucces').show();
         window.setTimeout("closeSuccess();", 10000);

         function closeSuccess(){
         document.getElementById("statsuccess").style.display=" none";
     }
      });  
  });  
 return false;  
  });
});
```

This is the input field I am trying to use to do a status update

`#profile_field_13_5` and the form action again is `/profile.php`

Thanks for whomever helps me

Comment: Does anyone have any clues on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting the form then do it this way:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    // validate and process form here  
    $('.error').hide();
    var stat = $("#profile_field_13_5").val();
    if (stat == "") {
        $("#name_error").show();
        $("#profile_field_13_5").focus();
        return false;
    }
    var dataString = 'stat=' + stat;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/profile.php",
        data: {data:dataString}, //<---pass it this way
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data); // <----this will show the passed value
            }
        });

e.preventDefault(); //return false; <--preventDefault() is as same as return false;
});
```

Try this out and see if this helps.

Comment: I looked and it's saying the last line is what is throwing the error...

 `  });
e.preventDefault(); 
});`

Comment: just remove the `});` before `e.preventdefault()` it just a copy paste error from my side.

Comment: updated the answer. `});` remove the upper closing of `preventdefault`

Comment: oh ok yeah I figured it out finally. Though this made the page refresh and submission wasn't passed

Comment: Don't get it. your form made the page refresh and submission not done.

Comment: Is your `input` button `type='submit'`?

Comment: yes `input type="submit"` like I said this form is actually on another page. I am trying to submit it from all pages with a little pop up for status updates.